# Angular custom directive JQuery animate doesn't move the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-directive

I have a custom angular directive as such so when you click the element it will move down :
angular.module('plunker', [])

```
.controller('AnimateCtlr', function(){

})
.directive('clickToAnimate', function(){
  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {

        element.bind('click', function(){
        console.log('moving');
        console.log( $( this).text() );
        $(this).animate({top: '+=150'});
      });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            direction : '@'
        },
        link: linker  
    };
});
```

All the console.log works which detect the clicking event, but the problem is, the div doesn't move at all. What can be wrong here?

Plunker is here:  http://plnkr.co/edit/j1OMiZFrar71P742dY6W?p=preview

Comment: it animates just fine, your css is not correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you set the position to absolute on the element, then it should work fine

JS:

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
.controller('AnimateCtlr', function(){

})
.directive('clickToAnimate', function(){
  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {

        element.bind('click', function(){
        console.log('moving');
        console.log( $( this).text() );

        $(this).css({position: 'absolute'}) // can be done right here! But belongs in your CSS really.

        $(this).animate({top: '+=150'}, 300, function(){
          console.log('complete')
        });
      });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            direction : '@'
        },
        link: linker  
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When changing the `top` property, you need have either fixed or absolute positioning for it to have any effect. Your plunker had neither. Adding `position:absolute;` and an initial `top:100px;` did the trick.

http://plnkr.co/edit/FTY5iF72KZkRGnIOcm7C?p=preview